# How do I convert html friendly ascii code to a string in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, ascii, windows-runtime

I'm reading data from a webservice that returns html friendly ascii codes instead of text.  I'm trying to convert it into a string again for a WinRT app but I can't seem to find the right decoder.

For example:

`&#39;` should equal an apostrophe.

I've already tried htmldecode and urldecode, but they're not what I need. Also, I don't know what I'll be getting back so I don't want to hardcode any characters.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you only get numeric entities, or do you also get named entities (e.g. `&apos;`, `&nbsp;`, `&mdash;`, etc.)? More info here if you're not familiar with HTML entities: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML

Comment: What does "They're not what I need" mean?  What is the expected output, and what is the output you are actually getting?

Comment: "They're not what I need" means they don't work.  They only convert things like &lt; and &lgt; type data.  But not ascii codes.  They just return the exact same as what goes in.

@JoeWhite I also get named entities.  I may have to handle those manually, I'm not sure.  

I'll post the code that I have that works for the numeric entities.

Comment: Ugh!  False alarm. Thanks for all your help.  I had to run htmldecode twice!  Apparently it was encoded twice before being sent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reference System.Web and use :

```
 HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("htmlcode");
```

Comment: Yeah that did the trick.  The incoming data was actually encoded twice, and I had to run htmldecode twice.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've got this bit of code that handles the numeric entities.

```
 Regex r = new Regex("&#[^;]+;");
 str = r.Replace(str, delegate(Match match)
 {
     string value = match.Value.ToString().Replace("&#", "").Replace(";", "");
     int asciiCode;
     if (int.TryParse(value, out asciiCode))
     {
         return Convert.ToChar(asciiCode).ToString();
     }
     else
     {
         return value;
     }                 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` doesn't give you what you need, you may have to write a regular expression or other comparison to loop through your string, matching the value from the HTML Number or HTML Name columns in [the HTML Codes table](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) so you can convert it to the corresponding symbol.

Comment: Thanks for you help. It's my fault for not spending more time on checking out the incoming data.  It was encoded twice so I had to decode twice.